# How to make a background image move in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

How do you move a background image in libgdx. So basically I want to move the background image up to create the moving effect for my racing game. So making the background image move would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want to have two backgrounds and move them in one direction then once one background is out of the screen make it go back up ok?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that if you are using Cameras that camera.position.x and camera.position.y are the center of the camera so if you want to position an image over the whole screen at all times you would do something like:

```
imageX = camera.position.x - camera.viewportWidth / 2;
imageY = camera.position.y - camera.viewportHeight / 2;
```

and then to move it you do something like this (in update or render method)

```
imageY += 5 * delta;
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare a position of your background

```
float x=0,y=0;
```

To draw it use

```
batch.draw(texture,x,y);
```

Now if you want the bg to go up in the render or update method write

```
y-=speed;
```

Now your background is going up.